# Is there a way to update the JDK without manually downloading the new version?

Tags: java, auto-update

I just got an Java update notification that Update 17 is out, so I ran the update and found that only my public JRE was updated. I still only have Update 16 of the JDK.

**Is there a way to have the latest JDK automatically when it's available?**

Of course, the update shouldn't get rid of old versions. That should be done manually since Eclipse is still using the old version. Once I've updated my settings I would delete the old JDK manually.

Comment: Windows: (Win 7 64-bits, but I have the 32-bit JDK)

Comment: This looks like an SuperUser or ServerFault question.

Comment: Nobody on ServerFault seems interested in answering that kind of question: http://serverfault.com/q/435894

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not on Windows. If you are getting your JDK via a linux distro with an auto-updater, you could depend on that. Somehow I doubt that is what you have in mind. I do not believe that there is any Sun-supplied auto-download for the JDK.

Comment: You could write an auto-download script yourself to get the latest JDK installer, just make it a scheduler task and it will run every night. The problem will be installing the new JDK, since I doubt the installer has a non-interactive mode.

Comment: Plus, Sun's Java download site has a few irritating click-through screens using long URL's full of ID's and such before you actually get to download the installer, so even the auto-download part wouldn't be a walk in the park.

Comment: How does Jenkins implement the auto install JDK feature ? I'm not familiar with the Jenkins code, but that is 1 place I know that installs JDK automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Under OS X this is part of the operating system and is automatically updated.  For Windows you must do it yourself.

Comment: Please note the comment date. This was accurate back in 2009 but is no longer accurate now.

Answer (score 1):

[Secunia PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) (a free version that runs on a single PC) will update it automatically. Read a review of it [here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406767,00.asp). If you're running both Java 6 and Java 7 JREs (like me), there can be glitches and you still have to update manually sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

[Ninite](https://ninite.com/) is a great website that lets you download the latest version of multiple applications/packages. If you save the installer, it will always pull the most recent version and download/install it without prompts. Reference: https://ninite.com/help/home/update.html

I did this myself just now, only caveat is that I had to delete the older jdk folder in "C:\Program Files\Java" in order for the "java -version" command to recognize the change.

Comment: **Update**: I also needed to modify the JAVA_HOME environment variable  to run applications that point to it. Windows 7: Control Panel --> System --> Advanced System Settings --> Advanced Tab --> Environment Variables

Comment: With the caveat that no security-conscious computer user would and should ever want to install any application not coming directly from its vendor.

Comment: I understand your point and agree that one should always be cautious when downloading anything from the internet. That being said, I would urge anyone to research the website for themselves. I have used it for years and it has saved time for countless others. More details on the process: https://ninite.com/security

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, `java` can now be installed through the Homebrew package manager. After installing Homebrew, you can simply run:

`brew cask install java`

to install the latest java version. It can then be kept up using

`brew cask reinstall java`